# Stopping frame animation

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am currently animating a view from left to right. However, I need to stop the animation mid-flight. To do this I use:

```
CGRect frame = [movingView layer] presentationLayer] frame];
[movingView.layer removeAllAnimations];
movingView.frame = frame;
```

Unfortunately the view appears to jump slightly to the left when this code is executed. How can I stop the animation in its exact place?

Comment: Have you read [Technical Q&A QA1673: How to pause the animation of a layer tree](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2009/qa1673.html) yet?

Comment: Also, what you are doing is mostly how you would do it. Note that the presentation layer is only an approximation of what is being displayed.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I had great hopes for the pause approach in the technical Q&A, but unfortunately it produces the same jump to the left.

Comment: How are you setting up the animation? Is it a key frame animation with a paced calculation mode?

Comment: I am just using [UIView animateWith...]. The animation is on a linear curve.

Comment: Does creating an explicit CABasicAnimation instead of animateWith... make any difference for the accuracy? Are you animating the frame or the position? Does it make a difference for the accuracy if you change it (only animate position of the size never changes etc.)?

Comment: I have now tried a CABasicAnimation for the position keypath. The jump to the left still remains :(